# How to make dropdown menu which will change titile to the name of the category in which we find ourselves in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to make dropdown menu which will change titile to the name of the category in which we find ourselves in wordpress ?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Did you try some line of code, at least?

Comment: Yes @carmine  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453678/why-does-not-display-selected-item-in-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside the wordpress loop,

```
$post_id = get_the_ID(); // or use the post id if you already have it
$category_object = get_the_category($post_id);
$category_name = $category_object[0]->name;
```

If you are outside the loop,

```
<?php $category_name = get_cat_name( $cat_id ) ?>
echo $category_name;
```

where `$id` is required.